# Glassfish JSF 2.0 charset problem

Tags: character-encoding, httpwebrequest, jsf-2, content-type, glassfish-3

I'm working on a project developed with JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.3) front end and deployed on Glassfish v.3.0.1 server. Application must accept ISO-8859-2 charset and write data to MySql database.
To problem is that data is not in right charset.
The request Http header has attribute value:

`content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

The problem is not with response, since data can be displayed correctly when read from database. Also, MySql connection URL should be correct because it is set for latin2 collaction. I even tried with creating [custom filter](http://www.jroller.com/mert/entry/utf_8_encoding_with_jsf), but without any result.

Any ideas how can I accomplish to accept correct charset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I gather you're using Facelets if you are using JSF 2.0. Then, do you have this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` at the top of your Facelet (XHTML) page. Just change **UTF-8** to **ISO-8859-2**. Also, check to see if you have META tags defined like `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>`. Change the encoding of this to ISO-8859-2 as well. Lastly, check your `DEFAULT CHARSET=ISO-8859-2` definition for your MySQL table(s). If it's not ISO-8859-2 then change it by using `ALTER TABLE` SQL command. That should be it. -:)

Comment: @user463053 Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I gave up on trying to set encoding to ISO-8859-2 and switched to UTF-8 encoding. Yes, I'm using Facelets and my pages had `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2">` tag. MySql default charset was set to latin2 and connectionURL contained `useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=ISO8859_2&amp;characterSetResults=latin2`. But, I'll try everything once again.

Comment: If after you have set everything to ISO-8859-2 and it still doesn't work, you can always write a Filter (See my answer) to force ISO-8859-2 encoding. However, changing it to UTF-8 should work for you since ISO-8859-2 character set can be found in UTF-8 - and being UTF-8 means you can add other character sets for other languages in the future without too much fuss. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always force **ISO-8859-2** encoding by creating a Filter and defining it in your `web.xml`. At a bare minimum, the Filter should have:

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       try {
          if ((request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
              && (response instanceof HttpServletResponse))  {
              request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-2");
              response.setContentType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2")
           }
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Do your logging here
        }
    }
}
```